# Access SQL - Error handling at run-time

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, jet

I have written a VBA function which builds an `INSERT INTO` query on the fly. This query calculates a score based on a formula that is selected from another table

e.g  The formula `"[Cash]/[Sales]"` would result in a query like:

```
INSERT INTO tblKPIScores
SELECT Employee, [Cash]/[Sales] as Score
FROM tblBasedata
```

In order to avoid div/0 errors I attempted to write another function that would be able to work out which part (if any) of the formula contained divisors and then test this in the SQL query separately e.g.

```
INSERT INTO tblKPIScores
SELECT Employee, IIF([Sales] = 0,0,[Cash]/[Sales]) as Score
FROM tblBasedata
```

However some of the formulas are very complex with lots of parentheses and may contain several divisors so I was unable to write a UDF that could reliably return the divisor(s) for any given formula.

I  am now trying something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblKPIScores
SELECT Employee, IIF(ISERROR(tScore),0,tScore) AS Score
FROM 
    (SELECT Employee, [Cash]/[Sales] as tScore
    FROM tblBasedata)
```

But instead of entering a zero this is still giving a #Num! error as I believe it is evaluating both parts of the IIF function and returning an error if either the true or false part evaluate to an error.

So my question is, is there any way to handle #Num! errors in SQL at runtime or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you define a Function to handle the division and call it in your SQL? By using Variant data-type you can also check for Null values. Change them as required.

```
Public Function SqlCalculation(ByVal value1 As Variant, ByVal value2 As Variant) As Double
    If value2 = 0 Then SqlCalculation = 0 Else SqlCalculation = value1 / value2
End Function
```

To call it in SQL:

```
INSERT INTO tblKPIScores (...)
SELECT Employee, SqlCalculation([Cash],[Sales]) as Score
FROM tblBasedata
```

Comment: Hi Kostas, thanks for the answer. The problem that I have is that although the example formula I gave in the question is quite simple, many of the other formulas are much more complex and contain multiple divisors. I did attempt to create a UDF to figure out the divisors for any given function but was unable to do so. That is why I was hoping to just catch the errors at run-time but I'm not sure if that's possible

Comment: OK I understand. I believe you need to check for zero each time orelse division will throw an error.